# How to query IBM Watson Discovery News with REST api?

Tags: api, rest, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

Is there an opportunity in IBM Watson Discovery News to query news just with the url where I can specify keywords, api etc. Would appreciate if anybody could share the template of such REST request. I created the account, launched the Discovery but then completely lost in the IBM Cloud API Docs https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/discovery. As far as I can see, here everything is for accessing via command line but it is not what I'm looking for...

This is what I used for Alchemy:

https://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/data/GetNews?apikey=&return=enriched.url.title&start=1477008000&end=now&q.enriched.url.cleanedTitle=InsertTitle&count=100&outputMode=xml

Best,
Lada

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally all you need to do is read the documentation - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/discovery#query-a-collection-get

```
curl -u "apikey":"{apikey}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/system/collections/news-en/query?version=2019-04-30&natural_language_query=corvid&count=10&return=text"
```

which becomes

```
https://apikey:{apikey}@gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/system/collections/news-en/query?version=2019-04-30&natural_language_query=corvid&count=100&return=text
```

although if you just run

```
https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/system/collections/news-en/query?version=2019-04-30&natural_language_query=corvid&count=10&return=text
```

you will be prompted for credentials.

You may need to amend the url endpoint to reflect the region you have your discovery service instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, doesn't work. I get {"code":403, "error": "Forbidden"}. And unfortunately, I don't know how to change the url endpoint to eu-de. Can the problem be that I use free Lite version?

Comment: No, the problem is that you have the wrong combination of url and apikey. You can get the right url from the same place you got your apikey, but the api docs show that the eu-de endpoint is: https://api.eu-de.discovery.watson.cloud.ibm.com

Comment: unfortunately, it is not clear from documentation what is right combination.

Comment: You can determine the right combination, but looking up the url at the same place you got your credentials. They come as a set.

Comment: yeah I have apikey and url with some specified instance, but how can I understand how to insert apikey in this url? I'm not a computer scientist and never worked with apis before, it is really not clear :) and I did read the documentation. There is no just one example of the whole url like this one that you sent: https://apikey:{apikey}@gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/system/collections/news-en/query?version=2019-04-30&natural_language_query=corvid&count=100&return=text but for my region